# Write a function capable of being passed to lapply

Tags: r, lapply

I have the following function:

```
expToLevel <- function(exp) {
    if(is.character(exp)) {
        return(exp)
    }
    for(i in 1:length(expTable)) {
        if(i+1 == 100) {
            return(99)
        }
        optr <- i + 1

        ntf = expTable[i]
        nto = expTable[optr]

        if(exp >= ntf & exp < nto) {
            return(i)
        }
    }

    return(0)
}
```

basically, it should take a given number, iterate through a list, and find the correct value. the function by itself works fine, and i'm not going for speed right now. the problem is that when I run `as.data.frame(lapply(myObj, FUN=expToLevel))` I get 50 errors, all saying:

`1: In if (exp >= ntf & exp < nto) { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`

any ideas?

i have a data frame of this structure:

```
> str(sc)
'data.frame':   5775 obs. of  25 variables:
 $ V1 : chr  "name1" "name2" "name3" "name4" ...
 $ V2 : num  617033491 1516909947 318531089 1881682119 764821383 ...
 $ V3 : num  13693391 13778068 3287842 48014739 54528460 ...
 $ V4 : num  13692714 13775391 3290310 48014766 21078118 ...
 $ V5 : num  13925555 23335843 4500664 49423442 26513175 ...
```

i want to lapply my function over this data frame and get the corresponding value from expTable. expTable is a list of 99 elements, and depending on the input, it will return a number between 1 and 99. however, if the input is greater than or equal to 13034431, it should return 99 by default.

Comment: This isn't reproducible

Comment: Those are NOT error messages.

Answer (score 1):

```
apply(df, MARGIN=c(1,2), FUN=expToLevel)
```

Comment: @sk099 To be honest I think you have a more fundamental issue going on with your code. And just truncating and grabbing the first value (by using && instead of &) is ignoring the larger issue at hand.

Comment: @sk099 i dunno `& and && indicate logical AND and | and || indicate logical OR. The shorter form performs elementwise comparisons in much the same way as arithmetic operators. The longer form evaluates left to right examining only the first element of each vector. Evaluation proceeds only until the result is determined. The longer form is appropriate for programming control-flow and typically preferred in if clauses` is pretty clear

Comment: I changed my answer, beacuse the problem was your call to lapply with a data frame : because the data.frame is a list of columns, lapply passes each column to your function which is actually designed for single values. That was the reason of your "error" message